# Iterate elements in flutter map

Tags: dart, flutter, maps

Im trying to get array of elements in flutter with map package.

I read [this](https://alfredeveloper.com/como-implementar-un-mapa-con-flutter/) tutorial to see how can i show more than one coordenates in flutter. This tutorial add elements manually, i need to add with api rest.

I created a foreach to retrieve all elements in array, then i add all coordinates in list. The problem: The list reset in initstate method, so i can´t take length of the list to loop for all coordenates.

This is the code:

```
 MapController mapController;
  Map<String, LatLng> coords;
  List<Marker> markers;
  List<Map<String, LatLng>> listado = [];

  Future<Null> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    for (Map user in responseJson) {
      coords.putIfAbsent("Test", () => new LatLng(user['lat'], user['long']));
      listado.add(coords);
     // print(listado.toList());
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = new MapController();
    coords = new Map<String, LatLng>();
    fetchPost();
    markers = new List<Marker>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listado.length; i++) {
      print(listado[1].values.elementAt(i));
      markers.add(new Marker(
          width: 80.0,
          height: 80.0,
          point: listado[1].values.elementAt(i),
          builder: (ctx) => new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.red[300])));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlutterMap(
      options: new MapOptions(
        center: new LatLng(37.7525244, 139.1650556),
        zoom: 5.0,
      ),
      mapController: mapController,
      layers: [
        new TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
        new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
      ],
    );
  }
}

final String url =
    'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/tobiobi/myjasonserver/coordinates';

//STATES
class UserDetails {
  final String name;
  final double lat, long;

  UserDetails({this.name, this.lat, this.long});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      name: json['name'],
      lat: json['lat'],
      long: json['long'],
    );
  }
}
```

So, how can i get all coordinates in list and iterate in loop?

**UPDATE**

I try

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = new MapController();
    coords = new Map<String, LatLng>();
    fetchPost().then((data) {
      print(data);
      for (int i = 0; i < listado.length; i++) {
        markers.add(new Marker(
            width: 80.0,
            height: 80.0,
            point: coords.values.elementAt(i),
            builder: (ctx) => new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.red[300])));
      }
    });
  }
```

But return 'the getter iterator was called on null'. The data has this json

```
 this: MapsPageState
 data: null
```

Inside *this* i have listado array and coords but ¿how can i get?

**UPDATE 2: SOLUTION**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:igota/screens/partials/alertmessages.dart';

class MapsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'maps-page';

  @override
  MapsPageState createState() => new MapsPageState();
}

class MapsPageState extends State<MapsPage> {
  MapController mapController;
  Map<String, LatLng> coords;
  List<Marker> markers;
  List<Map<String, LatLng>> list = [];
    int _counter = 0;


  bool loading;
  Future<Null> fetchPost() async {
    list = List();
    markers = List();
    mapController = new MapController();
    coords = new Map<String, LatLng>();
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/tobiobi/myjasonserver/coordinates').catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      AlertMessages.general(context,'No ha sido posible acceder a los datos');
    });
    final List responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    for (Map<String, dynamic> data in responseJson) {
            _counter++;

      coords.putIfAbsent("Test $_counter", () => new LatLng(double.parse(data['lat'].toString()),  double.parse(data['long'].toString())));
     list.add(coords);
     loading=false;
    }
    return;
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    loading = true;
    super.initState();

    fetchPost().then((data) {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        markers.add(new Marker(
            width: 80.0,
            height: 80.0,
            point: list[0].values.elementAt(i),
            builder: (ctx) => new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.red[300])));
      }
      setState( () { } );
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      AlertMessages.general(context, 'Problemas internos de código');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loading) {
      return new Container(
          color: Colors.red[300],
          child: new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
            ),
          ));
    } else {
      return new FlutterMap(
        options: new MapOptions(
          center: new LatLng(37.7525244, 139.1650556),
          zoom: 5.0,
        ),
        mapController: mapController,
        layers: [
          new TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
          new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
        ],
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So the main reason `listado.length` is zero when you try to iterate through it is because you didn't wait for `fetchPost();` method to finish its execution. You declared `fetchPost();` as a future which means it runs asynchronously.

What you need to do to ensure that by the time you attempt to iterate through `listado` is to perform the iteration in a call back method on the `fetchPost()`. So your code should look something like this:

```
fetchPost().then( (data){
  for (int i = 0; i < listado.length; i++) {
    print(listado[1].values.elementAt(i));
    markers.add(new Marker(
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
      point: listado[1].values.elementAt(i),
      builder: (ctx) => new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.red[300])
    ));
  }
});
```

This way, once `fetchPost()` completes, the callback method will be run and `listado' will have the latest data.

I'd advise you to also introduce a `isLoadingData` state which you set to `true` whenever you call `fetchPost()` and to `false` at the end of the callback method. Just so you can let the user know that you performing some kind of processing in the background and they don't have to stare at a blank page without any feedback on what's happening.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try your code but return 'the getter iterator was called on null'. I think is a for problem, maybe listado.length is not correct.I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the answer from @user8518697 and then do the following.

-initialize  markers as `List<Marker> markers = new List();` 
-use `for(int i = 0; i < (responseJson.length); i++)` instead of `for(Map user in responseJson)`

I also want to say thanks for your code. I have been able to use it to display multiple markers stored in a database.